# What is this type of sail boat hull construction?

Tags: boat-building

I am very slightly familiar with different type of sail boat/yacht hull construction. But this examples one on the pictures below are something that I do not quite understand.

First pic:
[image]

This I find puzzling. First it appears there are some bulkheads. Longitudinal "stringers" are fixed to them. I presume their only purpose is to define the hull shape, sort of like a spline. On this "stringers" the vertical frames are attached. This I presume will stay as structure of the boat. And i guess on top of this frames comes the planking. Then another assumption from me: inner bulkheads and "stringers" are removed so only frames and planking remain? Am I correct or wrong. Actually I would like this thing explained to me.

William Fife 8m Defender:
[image]

This looks very similar but on closer inspection I think longitudinal stringer are actual pieces of final planking. But I might be wrong.

This might be the same boat with planking.
[image]

So, at least the first pic shows the type of construction I do not understand. What is it?

Comment: I believe there is also some bent lamination involved to make the frame keep its shape. Having a mold for the entire keel makes it easier to keep each part of the boat in one place and make sure you have everything.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the second picture, you will see that the "underlying" longitudinal members (inside the ribs) in the first picture are just part of the **mold** which the vertical members (ribs) are attached to in bending/forming. They stay there and the next hull's vertical members are formed on them. That mold sets the shape of the hull for all boats built on it.

The longitudinal support on the finished hull comes from the planking attached to the outside of the ribs. The longitudinal members outside the ribs in the second picture may be some of those planks, but are more likely to be temporary braces to permit the ribs to stay in place until planking is attached, which will be removed as the planking gets to each one. Managing the joints between boards is difficult enough without adding trying to meet up with 10 or more boards already fixed in place.

Answer (score 2):

The longitudinal strips in the first picture are temporary members called 'ribbands' used to develope the shape of the bent ribs AKA called 'frames'. The ribs are either steamed (old school), or laminated in layers (usual modern way).

As the planks are fitted the ribbands are successively removed to make room for the clamps needed to hold the planks to the ribs as they are fastened off. The second picture shows the sheer plank ('strake') fastened off to the ribs. This process goes faster than you may think with a well-trained crew of shipwrights. Once a plank is laid out for one side, its twin is made for the other side. In fact, if the  planking isn't too thick to allow it, in  smaller boats, only one thick plank is made and then sawn in half lengthwise with both pieces then being re-planed to thickness. That helps keep the boat symmetrical.

If these pictures are all the same boat and I think they are, I do not understand why the builders would roll it rightside up to plank it. It is ever so much easier to work 'down' on something like a boat instead of working up and overhead! Maybe it was done for photography reasons.

Comment: The boat in the first picture doesn't have a keel yet, so no way to put it right side up. And boats are kind of heavy and maybe not so easy to flip ;) The deck structure ins't designed to take the whole weight of the boat, the keel is. Also usually everything is referenced to the keel. So you want to put that straight and level on the floor and not have ithanging somewhere in the air.

Comment: I was a professional boatbuilder before I retired. My shop built many boat hulls upside down then turned them over once the planking and 'fairing' (another subject) was finished. Since there is no deck at this point, strong temporary cross spalls (like beams) were installed to brace the hull. There are several ways to roll a hull over. You might be surprised in how narrow a space is required for a rollover operation which is a very careful process of course.